# terraform ddns reverse zone creation

Tags: terraform

I am attempting to automatically update DNS with terraform using the dns provider.  I have been successful with the forward zone but not the reverse zone.  My understanding is that PTR should be the host portion of the IP address.  I attempted to provide this using the below (sanitized):

```
# Configure Kubernetes DNS
provider "dns" {
  update {
    server = "<DNS IP ADDRESS>"
    key_name = "nsadmin."
    key_algorithm = "hmac-md5"
    key_secret = "<SECRET>"
  }
}

# Kubernetes master servers
resource "dns_a_record_set" "forward" {
  count = 2
  zone = "k8s.mydomain.example."
  name = "kubernetes-master${count.index + 1}"
  addresses = [
    "${lookup(var.ipv4_addresses_int1, count.index)}",
  ]
}
resource "dns_ptr_record" "reverse" {
  count = 2
  zone = "0.11.10.in-addr.arpa."
  name = "kubernetes-master${count.index + 1}"
  ptr  = "${element(split(".",lookup(var.ipv4_addresses_int1, count.index)),3)}""
}
```

I get an error:
* dns_ptr_record.reverse.0: Error creating DNS record: "ptr" should be an FQDN

What I am trying to do is lookup the IP address for that VM based on the count value, split it on the "." character and take the 3rd element.  Running a plan shows that this worked, but applying it obviously did not:

```
dns_ptr_record.reverse[0]: Creating...
  name: "" => "kubernetes-master1"
  ptr:  "" => "1"
  ttl:  "" => "3600"
  zone: "" => "0.11.10.in-addr.arpa."
```

In the example on the terraform documentation for dns_ptr_record ptr is a domain name, that resulted in my trying to create entries in my reverse zone such as:

```
example.com.0.11.10.in-addr.arpa
```

Can someone please advise the correct way to do this?

The documentation is very vague and I can't find any tutorials or decent examples anywhere.

Comment: Name and ptr are backwards, name is '1' and ptr is the target or `$(hostname)`, you may also need a trailing period depending on the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the PTR and NAME variables.

```
resource "dns_ptr_record" "reverse" {
  count = 2 
  zone = "0.11.10.in-addr.arpa." 
  name = "${element(split(".",lookup(var.ipv4_addresses_int1, count.index)),3)}"
  ptr = "kubernetes-master${count.index + 1}.k8s.example.com."
}
```

Comment: Great, that worked.  I also had to put the full domain in the ptr so it is now:  ptr = "kubernetes-master${count.index + 1}.k8s.example.com."

Comment: Makes sense, haven't used terraform yet